# cannot log in to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to log in to SQL Server 2008, but the installation and the log_in user were done by my friend. Now I'm to trying to open the management studio but I get the error message "login failed" although SQL Server service is running. How can I check if the user is member of Server Admin role?

Comment: Did you friend leave you with the sa password? Are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Did you check if SQL Service is accessable over network? By default installation is blocking over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ability to log into the OS either remotely or locally and you have been granted elevated privileges, you have a couple of options...

1. Execute T-SQL queries using SQLCMD under the SYSTEM account. You should be able to build out the T-SQL to add your account to the sysadmin fixed server role.
2. Add your account to the SQL Server Database Engine service group. More information available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#New_Accounts)